# Display image based on Gridview selection from previous activity

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, imageview

I currently have a working gridview displaying some thumbnails. Currently, when you select an image it will save a larger resolution of the image as a wallpaper.

What I want to do is open a new intent and then display the full resolution image based on the GridView position clicked. I'm not sure how I find out what position was clicked from the new activity/intent.

Heres what I have in my main activity

```
public class test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(test.this, "" + position + "" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Make a Bitmap from the Resource
            ImageAdapter i = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),(int)i.getItemId(position));

            //Get the WallpaperManager
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                //Set the clicked bitmap
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                Toast.makeText(test.this, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(test.this, "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mFullSizeIds[position];
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
        R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
        R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6,
        R.drawable.sample_7 
};


private Integer[] mFullSizeIds = {
        R.drawable.wallpaper1,
        R.drawable.wallpaper2,
        R.drawable.wallpaper3,
        R.drawable.wallpaper4,
        R.drawable.wallpaper5,
        R.drawable.wallpaper6,
        R.drawable.wallpaper7
        };
```

}

And blank FullView template

```
public class FullView extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullview);

ImageView imageview;
    imageview.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[**]) <--- How to set ** to what GridView position was selected?


}
```

}

I haven't really written anything in the FullView activity yet due to being unaware of how to pass the position that was clicked from the GridView in this new activity.

(I haven't written the intent code in my main activity either so you can see how it currently works)

How do I pass the gridview position that was selected into the new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler (the OnItemClickListener), you can get the resource ID of the image as mThumbs[position]. Add this as an extra to the Intent you use to start your FullView Activity.