# Set content based on a decision from a previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically I want to set a image based on a previous activity. There is just ListView of locations(first activity), and just show a picture of the location based on the selection(second activity).

I know it will have to do something with Intents, but other than starting a new activity.

Are there super simple example I could read, I tried to understand

[Display image based on Gridview selection from previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740470/display-image-based-on-gridview-selection-from-previous-activity)

but I couldn't really get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you start the new activity, you can use the intent in the following way:

```
yourIntent.putExtra("Decision", theDecision);
startActivity(yourIntent);
```

And in the new activity:

```
int theDesicion = getIntent.getIntExtra("Desicion");
```